# What does “purple” mean in “earthworms frolicked purple in the slush”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does purple mean, other than its definition which tells what type of color it is, in the below paragraph:

> Heaven opened and the water hammered down, reviving the reluctant old well, greenmossing the pigless pigsty, carpet bombing still, tea-coloured puddles the way memory bombs still, tea-coloured minds. The grass looked wetgreen and pleased. Happy **earthworms frolicked purple in the slush**. Green nettles nodded. Trees bent.

This para is from God of small things by Arundhita Roy.

Comment: Earthworms are often a purple colour. They frolicked and looked purple. No mystery here.

Comment: No meaning other than colour, in other words.

Comment: You can read a [**purple passage**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/purple_passage) but the text is the same colour as the rest of the book. What do you suppose a *tea-coloured mind* is, or how grass can *look pleased*? The text you quote is itself **purple**.

Comment: @WeatherVane here frolicked is used as verb which means to move playfully. So frolicked (moved playfully) purple doesn't make sense. It should be : " happy purple earthworm frolicked in slush."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although the cited text is "prose", it's ***highly poetical language*** (for example, *minds* can't be "tea-coloured", there's no such word as "wetgreen", and *grass* can't really look "pleased"). Which to me make this question as Off Topic as lyrics/poetry interpretation.

Comment: sb1, this is poetic language. The writer is free to write what she wants. In any case, the adjective 'purple' may follow the verb 'frolicked'. No error. If they were yellow one could write that they 'frolicked golden'.

Comment: Ok i get it now Thank you. I think I should stop stressing on the grammar.

Comment: (At least *some* readers will pick up overtones of ***purple = engorged** [with blood]*, suggesting a tumescent state of [sexual] arousal. But that doesn't need to imply the writer *intended* that somewhat coarse allusion.)

Comment: @Fumblefingers - indeed.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, I'm no biologist. But if I saw worms (of any colour) apparently "frolicking" in ***slush***, I'd probably assume they were ***drowning***, not having fun! Maybe I'm just not sufficiently romantic!

Comment: FumbleFingers,  I agree that it is poetic language, **but** it's apparently written in a paragraph as if it were prose.   I think it's a valid question:  a Good Answer to this question would confirm for the questioner that **this text is hard to decipher** because "This is poetic language" (@Michael Harvey) or "It's highly poetical language" (@FumbleFingers).

Comment: Paragraphs of text which appear to be 'prose' can be regarded as poetic in nature, and Arundhita Roy is well-known for her 'poetic prose'.

Comment: It's not at all hard to decipher.  It just means that they are purple!   Using this in a place where you'd expect an adverb "tricks you" into actually visualizing them - so it's striking language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copular or linking verbs such as *be*, *seem*, *feel*, *become*, *look*, (when meaning seem) will allow adjectives to appear where an object would appear for another verb.

A device used in poetic or literary language is to use a non-copular verb as a copular one.  A meaning of one of the typical copular verbs is being blended with the non-copular verb.

A possible meaning when this is done is *become X by {verb}* or *did X and looked X while doing {verb}*:

> Happy earthworms frolicked purple in the slush.
>
> Happy earthworms looked purple while the frolicked in the slush.

@BanZen expresses the idea well, the intent is to "trick" the reader into visualizing something.